# Was the nath sampradaya ( whose head his Yogi adityanath now) was created against brahmanism?

Tags: history

I remember reading it somewhere.

Any backstory?

Comment: If the asker has read somewhere why not citing sources?

Comment: @parthasarathy raghavan actually it was more like a discussion thing with a UPSC aspirant who was eventually from gorakhpur. I don't think Instagram Stories is a source worth citing.

Comment: Thanks for the question. This is however off-topic to the best of my knowledge. See this question on meta for details. [Political and Scientific questions are off-topic for Hinduism SE](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/121/21103)

Comment: @severus-snape I don't think the question is off-Topic. It's specific about a sampraday of Hinduism and my query seems understandable too.

Comment: Discussion may vary in different angles. But HSE has got some principles to ask a question. Instaram, google are all modern era things. What purana says can be accepted. Particularly against a caste is not forming part in HSE.